# What's the Fourier transform of $f(x)/x$?

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-mechanics

What's the Fourier transform of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$? Is it even defined? Because I was thinking of the time dependent Schrödinger's equation for an electric potential:
$$ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \Psi + \frac{kq_1 q_2}{r} \Psi = i\hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} $$

So, I have to take the transform to solve it, but how do I take the transform of the potential part?

Comment: The Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the transforms. Try to convolve the transform of $f$ with that of $x^{-1}$, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Keep in mind there are other ways to solve the equation without Fourier Transforms. It's  a good practice to  learn multiple methods.

Comment: Ahhhm... are you solving it in 1 or 3 dimensions?

Comment: @YvesDaoust But when I try taking the Fourier transform of 1/r (converting to spherical) it diverges...

Comment: @TurlocTheRed Yes, I know how to solve it by separating variables, and I was trying a different method.

Comment: @CosmasZachos 3 dimensions.

Comment: But then your 1/x is resoundingly irrelevant, no?

Comment: @Dah_Fisicist: this is why I said "if that makes any sense".

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help.

Suppose $\Psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(k)e^{ikx}dk$.

So $\Psi(x)$ is the Fourier Transform of $\phi(k)$.

Take the derivative of either side with respect to $x$.

$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty ik\phi(k)e^{ikx}dk$

So we can get the transform of multiplying by a power of k if we just do the transform of $\phi$ then take the derivative of the transform.

This suggests integrating the transform with respect to $x$ to divide and get the transform of $\phi(k)/k$.

There are some restrictions on the method. The function which is to be integrated with respect to $k$ has to converge, so multiplying or dividing by powers of $k$ will only work for certain values of $\phi(k)$.